# generate activerecord schema from an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, schema

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I have an existing table that I created with sql and I would like to create a schema from it that would reproduce the table (minus the data)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Edit config/database.rb to point to the database you want copied.
2. `rake db:schema:dump`
3. Create a blank migration
4. Copy the relevant `create_table` lines from the schema dump and paste it into the migration file
5. Manually insert the migration timestamp into schema_migrations table (this applies to existing setup only as it already has the relevant table)

Comment: This got me on the right path, I finally settled on: `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump ActiveRecord::Base.connection, File.open('schema.rb', 'w')`

Comment: @pguardiario - You should consider adding your comment as an answer. Your solution was the one that I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

A schema is written in [your app]/db/schema.rb.
Hope this help!

Comment: My question is how to generate such a file from an existing table.