# something similar to sqlautocode for rails (auto-generate models from existing db schema)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way to inspect a database schema and auto-generate models in Rails. Does anyone know of a project/gem that does this?

Comment: ActiveRecord already does this, in part. If you have a schema which details a users table with various columns, you just have to write `class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end` and you have getters / setters for the columns. So you still need to create model files for each time. I'm not aware of a model auto-gen library.

Comment: Is there a way to make active record inspect the database so that it can be used? How will active record be able to wrap around the database schema without inspecting it at all?

Comment: active record looks at the schema, not the database. There is apparently a way to generate a schema from your database (see [generate-activerecord-schema-from-an-existing-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879184/generate-activerecord-schema-from-an-existing-table) but there is no need to do this if you're using migrations to alter the database.

Answer (score 1):

Active Record is good for this. If you want to use it outside rails, then

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # In case the table name not following rails convention
  self.table_name = 'bar'
end

db_config = {
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  database: 'foobar'
}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)
```

That's all.

Comment: will this work the same way within rails as well? or does rails require that the database have certain conventions (like names or schema)

Comment: In Rails, you can just omit the the part that starts from `db_config = ...`